# how to calling a php function when submitting a ninja form?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a ninja_form in my Wordpress website, I need to call a php function when submitting this ninja_form, how can I do this?

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
function ninja_forms_register_example(){
  add_action( 'ninja_forms_process', 'ninja_forms_example' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'ninja_forms_register_example' );

function ninja_forms_example(){
  global $ninja_forms_processing;

  //Get all the user submitted values
  $all_fields = $ninja_forms_processing->get_all_fields();

  if( is_array( $all_fields ) ){ //Make sure $all_fields is an array.
  //Loop through each of our submitted values.
    foreach( $all_fields as $field_id => $user_value ){
      //Do something with those values
    }
  }
}`
```

http://docs.ninjaforms.com/article/105-ninjaformsprocess